# Image uploader with ReactJS and Spring REST

Tags: javascript, spring, rest, reactjs, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to create an image uploader with ReactJS as the front-end, and Spring REST for the back-end. My current approach is to use [react-dropzone](https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone) as the image placeholder, and [rest.js](https://github.com/cujojs/rest) to send the image to the back-end.

I'm using `client.js` file from Spring Data REST tutorial. After researching, I decided to send the image as `multipart/form-data` in a POST request.
Here's my onDrop function inside react-dropzone component:

```
onDrop(files) {
    files.forEach((file)=> {
        client({
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/api/upload',
            entity: file,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        }).done(() => console.log('success!'));
    });
}
```

and on the Spring REST controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/api/upload", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
...
}
```

However, I've got this error: `POST http://localhost:8080/api/upload 400 (Bad Request)`

Not sure whether the problem is on the REST client or the controller. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Not seeing any code to generate the multipart/form-data body, you're just sending a file as the body.  See [this](/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: @Tibrogargan I just realized it. Thanks.